# Why is the form "Antares" used as an ablative in some Latin texts?

Tags: declension, ablative

Jam inquiro nomen stellae *Antares.* Multa documenta quae "ab Antares" dicunt comperi. At non scio ablativi qui in "es" terminantur. Potestne nomen "Antares" indeclinabile esse? Quare?

Exempla:

- "Lanx Borae ab Antares", et alia. *[Almagestum nouum astronomiam veterem nouamque...](https://books.google.com/books?id=n3vI84z0AfkC&pg=PA430&lpg=PA430&dq=%22ab%20antares%22),* P. Ioanne Baptista, MDCLI.
- "Ideo distantiam Saturni ab Antares tribus minutis breuiorem accipimus idest...", *[Ephemerides Novissimae Motuum Coelestium](https://books.google.com/books?id=g0JTAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=%22ab%20antares%22),* MDCLXII
- *[Pandora mathematicarum tabularum](https://books.google.com/books?id=QBcHAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA6-PA354&lpg=RA6-PA354&dq=%22ab%20antares%22)*, 1684

Video quoque "ab Antare":

- *[Historia Coelestis Britannica](https://books.google.com/books?id=LzxTAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA1-PA144&lpg=RA1-PA144&dq=%22ab%20antare%22)*
- *[Philosophical Transactions](https://books.google.com/books?id=wvwSuBLY6GgC&pg=PA574&lpg=PA574&dq=%22ab%20antare%22)*